# Subbmiting form with array of text fields

Tags: laravel

I want to save 3 items as '1' batch into my database simultaneously

batch have names of

1.Test1

2.Test2

3.Test3

My form has name as 'product_name'

How would you process a array and insert the  following item names into the database simultaneously when a user hit the submit button...

Database ==mysql

Comment: "_In the text field the input name of the field to handle the product name's is 'product_name';_" What does that mean?

Comment: Also, what is your database (SQL, ORACLE, etc) and do you use an ORM in your solution (Entity Framework, nHibernate, etc)?

Comment: Show us some of your code... What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

```
$pro1= Input::get("product_name.0");
$pro2= Input::get("product_name.1");
An example here,
for($i= 0; $i<= $count-1; $i++)
{
    $ctgryLabels=   new CategoryLabelModel;
    $ctgryLabels->category_id= 1;
    $ctgryLabels->label= Input::get('label.'.$i);
    $ctgryLabels->label_controls= Input::get('control.'.$i);
    $ctgryLabels->label_status= 1;                            
    $ctgryLabels->save();
}
```